# red5 external access not working

Tags: red5

When I run an install of any red5 exe... lets say 1.o.1...and I input (10.0.0.2) as the ip on the prompt and 5080 as port... local I can see my home screen... but cannot access /install  /demo

If I run install with (127.0.0.1) I can see and reach the aforementioned but cannot reach any pages from an external machine or external ip...

what pages are edited with the ips after I enter on exe screen... just .properties?

where are the paths for install and demo located?

Answer (score 0):

Test the server using the IP of 0.0.0.0 (initial default, meaning bind to all). This should work for internal and external access. There aren't any "pages" that are edited per se when you enter the IP at install time, the file at red5/conf/red5.properties is modified. The path to the install app would be red5/webapps/install and if you mean oflaDemo instead of "demo", you have to install it as it doesn't come with the server in most cases.